# Thread.Sleep() vs Task.Delay().Wait()

Tags: c#, .net, task, task-parallel-library, thread-sleep

Codebase was like this in a non-async¹ method:

```cs
Thread.Sleep(500);
```

A colleague refactored it to be like this:

```cs
Task.Delay(500).Wait();
```

Given the relative small delay, is really an advantage to use the async version (`Task.Delay()`) ?
Does it change if the delay is a bunch of millisecond or a bunch of seconds ?
More important... Is not the `.Wait()` defeating he purpose of making an async ?

To provide more context, this is executes in a background process that runs an average of every minute.

Isn't this second approach just wasting more resources ? (as some comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27820626/difference-between-task-delay-and-new-task-thread-sleep) seems to indicate)

**[Edit]**
The `await` is not used in this case because the method is NOT `async`.
My colleague prefers `Task.Delay(N).Wait()` to `Thread.Sleep(N)`.
Where the method is async he used `await` and not `.Wait()`.

In this specific case the method is called when an API endpoint is hit and send a request to an external service and tries 3 or 5  times (with a delay) until it gets the result (kind of polling).

¹ <sub>Originally the method was mentioned to be async.</sub>

Comment: `await` has its own advantages, such as not blocking the UI, or not holding up a threadpool thread. But they're not using that here, and that's wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to use Task.Delay, when to use Thread.Sleep?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20082221/when-to-use-task-delay-when-to-use-thread-sleep)

Comment: If the method is really asynchronous use `async Task.Delay(5000)`. If you can't it's not asynchronous. Both options here wasting a thread but the second also wastes CPU by spinwaiting before putting the thread to sleep. If, and only if, the spinwait duration is less than the wait duration, the application will resume faster. And 500ms is almost certainly longer than the spinwait duration

Comment: The *real* question should be why isn't `await Task.Delay()` used here?

Comment: The " When to use Task.Delay, when to use Thread.Sleep?  " post
answers my question in part... like also the other post I (I think) mentioned.
As I said, I was not sure why the ``.Wait`` was used instead of the``await`` (I'm not sure, but maybe who did this refactor, copy paste in many places... async and not-async)

Comment: Every program has at least one thread. Even an `async int Main()` must have a thread somewhere. A single background thread? It doesn't really matter. But it's a bad habit to get into. Some time in the future you might wonder why your web server is running out of threads...

Comment: Yes, very wasteful.  Bigger issue is that you never want to introduce a random thread context switch that nobody can easily see or, even here, has thought of.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```cs
await Task.Delay(500);
```

You should *almost never* <sup>†</sup> use `.Wait()`, but `Task.Delay(...).Wait()` is a special circle of "nope".

`Thread.Sleep(...)` is *ok* if you are happy with blocking the current thread; you shouldn't do that on a concurrent application (such as a server), though.

---

<sup>†</sup> yes, there are scenarios where it is acceptable or even necessary; but *if you have to ask*: "don't" is a good default answer; any *full* answer on this involves multiple pages of context, nuance, etc.

Answer (score 3):

> Codebase was like this:
>
> ```
> Thread.Sleep(500);
> ```
>
> A colleague refactored it to be like this:
>
> ```
> Task.Delay(500).Wait();
> ```

Your colleague's refactoring constitutes neither an improvement nor a regression. Both commands block the current thread for 500 milliseconds. Functionally there is no difference between them. If one is more precise than the other (in the order of a milliseconds), it's probably the `Thread.Sleep(500)`, but I haven't tested experimentally this theory.

The mechanism that blocks the current thread is not exactly the same. In the case of the `Thread.Sleep` there is a direct call to the `Interop.Kernel32.Sleep` API ([source code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/v8.0.0/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Thread.Windows.cs#L20)). In the case of `Task.Delay`+`Wait` there is much more going on. It involves the .NET  [`TimerQueue`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/v8.0.0/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Timer.cs) infrastructure, a `ManualResetEventSlim` for blocking the current thread until a signal comes from the said infrastructure, and eventually deep in this infrastructure there should be a `Interop.Kernel32.Sleep` as well that manages the activity of the dedicated .NET thread that ticks the timers. But in the grand scheme of things all these are happening very fast, and you shouldn't see any measurable negative effect in performance by using your colleague's approach.

It is mostly painful for the eyes of the reviewers though, to see a simple line of code replaced by a less simple line of code that does the same thing, but requires significantly more mental effort to comprehend. Including the mental effort associated with querying the intentions behind this unwarranted complexity.

---

**Caution:** As Marc Gravell mentioned [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78060027/thread-sleep-vs-task-delay-wait/78064515?noredirect=1#comment137626488_78064515), the `Task.Delay(500).Wait();` relies on the availability of a `ThreadPool` thread to complete the `Task.Delay` task that signals the awakening of the blocked thread. So in a scenario where the `ThreadPool` is saturated, the `Task.Delay(500).Wait();` can become remarkably innacurate, extending the delay time by many seconds. Theoretically it could even cause a deadlock in a scenario where the `ThreadPool` has reached its [maximum size](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool.getmaxthreads), and the saturation incident can't be resolved by injecting more threads. The maximum size of the `ThreadPool` is normally pretty high (32,767 in my machine for a console app), so this scenario is quite unlikely to occur in practice.

Comment: "Your colleague's refactoring constitutes neither an improvement nor a regression." plus "In the case of Task.Delay+Wait there is much more going on.:" - IMO that "much more" represents a distinct *regression*; I wondered whether it might even be able to cause a sync-context related deadlock, although a quick test in winforms doesn't *suggest* that is an immediate concern; either way, I think it is very misleading to describe `Task.Delay(...).Wait()` as anything other than a regression - it isn't purely cosmetic, IMO

Comment: @MarcGravell the mere nature of *sleeping* makes it impossible to *"run"* in parallel, or in quick succession, so I can't think of a way to measure its impact in terms of performance. Are you really concerned that the computational overhead of `Task.Delay(500).Wait()` would ever make a noticeable difference in any type of application? Let's be realistic, and raise our concerns only where they ought to be raised.

Comment: Yes, absolutely I am concerned. Thread-pool contention is a real thing; I would have grave concerns about causing and getting stuck in a TP spiral in loaded scenarios. For context: I work mostly in library/framework layers, rather than application layers, so I am *all about* small things with big side effects.

Comment: @MarcGravell hmm, OK. If you wanted to prove that the `Task.Delay(500).Wait()`, or even the shorter `Task.Delay(1).Wait()`, can become the computational bottleneck of an application, how would you prove it?

Comment: you misunderstand; this isn't about computational overhead - it is about overall system impact - again, emphasis on the TP spiral which *is a thing*; but if I wanted to *measure* the computation overhead, I'd need the context of the computation; we can measure in isolation (they are roughly paired, when no competing load, so: indeed, in any happy system: there won't be a significant difference) - but again: focusing on that is *entirely missing the point*; the delta is about contested scenarios; I feel I could paraphrase "doing this the clearly dumb way doesn't hurt me" - it is still dumb

Comment: @MarcGravell what is a TP spiral? I am not aware of the term.

Comment: @MarcGravell btw [your original comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78060027/thread-sleep-vs-task-delay-wait/78064515?noredirect=1#comment137625172_78064515) was about the non-purely-cosmetic regression, and I am responding to your comment. So focusing on the performance impact is exactly on point. Judging the colleague's refactoring in terms of foolishness is off topic here.

Comment: thread-pool (TP) starvation - if you manage to make the TP stutter, i.e. briefly run out of available workers - and if you're depending on the thread-pool to unblock other things running on the thread-pool: you can quickly reach a point of no return (due to slow TP growth); `Task.Delay` could potentially contribute to that in ways that `Thread.Sleep` won't

Comment: @MarcGravell good point. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @MarcGravell btw your comment gave me a déjà vu moment. Alexei Levenkov has made a [similar observation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74341383/will-calling-task-result-cause-a-deadlock-if-configureawaitfalse-is-used#comment131246611_74342953) under an other answer of mine, which I had to edit as well.

Comment: for context, I work on the asp-net team, and maintain highly threaded library code like SE.Redis - it is the kind of niche problem that *application* code will almost never hit, but library/framework code can be in danger of running into; some nightmare scenarios are simply ... niche, but those niches are real :)

Comment: @TheodorZoulias you see thread pool starvation IS a thing in server environments! Maybe the virtues of `Task.Yield` are more apparent now? :D

Comment: @EmperorEto the virtues of `Task.Yield` compared to what? To `Task.Run`? First, this discussion is off-topic here. Second, the `Task.Yield` has no virtue over `Task.Run`. When used for the purpose of offloading, they both need a `ThreadPool` thread, so they'll both stutter when there is none available.

Comment: No not compared to Task.Run. Compared to allowing threads to be blocked by long running ops without ever yielding (regardless of the method of yielding). IIRC you didn't agree thread pool starvation was a genuine concern.

Comment: @EmperorEto I think that the saturation of the `ThreadPool` is a serious problem, and developers should be aware of it and take preventive actions against it. If your `ThreadPool` is saturated, your application will suffer one way or another. And I am still failing to understand how is this related to the `Task.Yield`. Are you trying to continue here the discussion we had two weeks ago under your [now deleted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22645024/when-would-i-use-task-yield/78061358#78061358) on an unrelated question?

Comment: It's more about your comment in your *not* deleted answer there that "if you have a problem with a saturated ThreadPool, and hope to fix it by splitting each big job to many smaller jobs, a better solution might be to configure your ThreadPool...." Maybe I misunderstood but it seemed to my naive eyes that you didn't think blocking individual threads was a concern because you can just crank up the limit. I think this Q&A is quite related because it goes to the point that blocking threads is never good no matter how many you think you have available.

Comment: @EmperorEto the `Task.Delay(500).Wait();` doesn't block more threads than the `Thread.Sleep(500);`. They both block the current thread for 500 msec. This question is not about whether blocking threads is good or bad. It's about whether blocking a thread one way is better than blocking it another way. Honestly I think that your three comments above are off-topic here. If you have anything to say that is relevant to this question and answer, please do.

Comment: Hm, no I read this Q/A differently, but thank you for clarifying.